# Cambiar el puerto de un endpoint con el cliente SOAP de Python - Zeep

Tags: python, soap, puertos, zeep

Disculpen, tengo un endpoint el cual me muestra ciertos servicios web, dicho endpoint es el siguiente:

wsdl = "http://xxxxxxxx:8080/xxxx/xxxx?WSDL"

El problema está en que, al momento de querer obtener el cliente para poder obtener los servicios web, el método **zeep.Client()** inicializa or default el puerto con un valor de 80, contrario al endpoint, el cual tiene como valor 8080.

De acuerdo a lo poco que he investigado, (lo cual no sé si sea lo correcto), para especificar el valor de un puerto específico para un endpoint, necesitas especificar el siguiente parámetro al momento de crear el cliente SOAP:

client = zeep.Client(wsdl = wsdl, ***port_name = 8080***, settings =  settings)

Lo cual, al momento de ejecutar el programa, me muestra el siguiente mensaje:

An exception has ocurred: Port not found

Comment: Jesús, creo que el puerto lo pones directamente en la URL, algo así: client = zeep.Client(wsdl = "http://xxxxxxxx:8080/xxxx/xxxx?WSDL", settings = settings).  ¿No te funciona de esta manera?

Comment: No, no funciona